# how to filter part of a path in iOS?

Tags: ios, path, explode, filepath

we have an app released, which wasn't held for developer release. Our customer released the app instead of waiting for us changing the backend for the new version. This now leads to wrong information at a local CoreData Storage, where the problem begins.

There seems to be a field holding a local path to a file on Documents directory like:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/9EE88C79-F060-4EE....C0A/Documents/core23/thumb.png
```

The folder where the App lives in on local device changes during the update of an app (looks like!?). Now we need to filter this field to change the path before `/Documents/`to the actual path where the app is installed on local device.

Does somebody have a handy solution for that? Any help is appreciated.

MadMaxApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[NSString pathComponents]` returns an array of all path components. Call that on your errant path string and build it back up from the resulting array.

`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString*)]` would also work just as well if passed `@"/"` for the separator string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hard code that path. To get the documents directory path use the following code:

```
-(NSString *)documentsDirectoryPath {
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
      return documentsDirectoryPath;
}
```

Comment: i Know ... that's how the path is calculated. But because of a condition that came active because of the missing changes at the backend, now the local sql.lite database holds the whole path, not only /Documents/.... That's why we need to filter the path-value. Delete everything in Front of /Documents/... and store it back to database.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I thought you had hard-coded the path :)